# Downloading the source of my Heroku site from Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I built a Ruby on Rails application that is running on Heroku.

For reasons currently unknown to me, the page formatting of my web app has gotten a bit messed up on my local source code, and I'd like to download the not-messed-up copy from Heroku, and work with that instead.

Is there any way to do this?  Thanks in advance.

By the way, I tried downloading the CSS files from the Heroku hosted site, and it still doesn't look right.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to clone it:

```
git clone git@heroku.com:your-app.git
```

Comment: And he should be using his own git repository (possibly github.com) for keeping track of his changes as he works.

Comment: @mu sometimes I keep my code JUST on Heroku if it's something I don't want the public to see.

Comment: @Dty: I'd recommend against that, setting up a git repository isn't that hard and it would let you experiment and track changes without having to publish your changes to a production system.

Comment: @mu sorry, I meant that I push my git repository to Heroku only (and not onto github). It acts as my private (and free) offsite git repo backup.